# Sum and store values in another table

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am new to Django. My query is
I store some quantity of components in a table. I want to sum the quantity sorting it by components and then use the summed quantity in some other table to do further calculations. How can I achieve this..

**#views.py**

```py
class PurchaseCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Purchase
    fields = '__all__'
    success_url = reverse_lazy("purchase_form")

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['purchases'] = Purchase.objects.all()
        return context
```

**#models.py**

```py
class Purchase(models.Model):
    purchase_date = models.DateField()
    invoice_no = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True)
    supplier =models.ForeignKey(Supplier,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    components = models.ForeignKey(Components,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    remarks = models.TextField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk)
```

***# Below is the Model where I want to use the summed quantity for further calc***

```py
class IntermediateStage(models.Model):
    producttype = models.ForeignKey(ProductType,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    components = models.ForeignKey(Components,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    processingstage = models.ForeignKey(ProcessingStage,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    unitsrequired = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank = True)**#want to store summed qty here**
    total_quantity = models.IntegerField(blank= True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['producttype','components','processingstage']]

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

**#Components Model**

```py
class Components(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    producttype = models.ManyToManyField(ProductType, through='IntermediateStage')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: The IntermediateStage model doesn't seem to be related to Purchase in any way. What is it exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: The Purchase model stores all the components required to make a product. For eg body , screw ,rack etc. So if i have two purchase enteries for body in Purchase, I wish to add them and use that quantity in the IntermediateStage model.

Comment: As it is, the Purchase model is linked to exactly one `Components` model. Can you show that model too?